# Call async await in angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

In my angular 2 app i got method:

```
myMethod(component: any): void {
  let a = console.log('start');
  if (this._something) {
    // Here i got custom modal window
    this._service.callModalWindow('message').subscribe(result => {
      if (result === 'Confirm') {
        let b = console.log('confirm);
      }
    }
  }
  let c = console.log('finish');
}
```

The problem is: The way this method call console.log is not what i want, i want to get first `console.log('first')`, then after i got my modal confirmed get `console.log('confirm')`, and then get the final `console.log('finish')`;

Now i have this situation, method calls variable `a`, then `c`, then `b` when i confirm modal.

Does anyone have any ideas how i can work around this situation?

Comment: Move `let c` right after `let b` ?!

Comment: @JonasWilms this is not a way, it was just a custom example to show my situation, i need to make this method exactly in this position

Comment: What's the difference between "confirm" and "finish" states? Also, `console.log` does not return anything.

Comment: Add everything out want to run as "finish.." in a seperate method and call it in subscribe after your "confirm"

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/async-await-angular-demo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not the most suitable way to use the async await. But if u must. use the `toPromise` to convert the observable to promise since async wait need promises to resolve behind the scene

```
async  myMethod(component: any): void {
  let a = console.log('start');
  if (this._something) {
  // Here i got custom modal window
  let result = await this._service.callModalWindow('message').toPromise();
  if (result === 'Confirm') {
    let b = console.log('confirm);
  }
  let c = console.log('finish');
}
```

Comment: this is what i was looking for =)

Comment: return type is `Promise<void>` though.. good thing to know when calling it